# VB code to automatically send email in an ASP.NET app

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a file in witch there is a mix of HTML, Javascript, and Visual Basic, it is actually a web site (when up and running).

On a click event, I'm able to reach a VB function (tested) but now, the email part.

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()

SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true
SmtpServer.Port = 25
SmtpServer.Host = "12345.com"

Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.From = "si@csnavigateurs.qc.ca"
mail.To.Add("pelletiera77@csnavigateurs.qc.ca")
mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
mail.Body = "Testing the 1 and 2"
SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

I was thinking it would work by itself but no, surely there is something to config out in order to make this work. It throws a server error right at `Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()` So I guess I have to include something?

The error is:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: What is the server error?

Comment: You have some references to a variable called `Smtp_Server`, where is that defined?  You also reference a variable called `e_mail`, where is that defined?  What is the actual error when you debug this?

Comment: Sorry david, fixed that, it was confusing yeah, and here is the error

Comment: Are you able to debug and get the actual error thrown at that line? SmtpClient requires the namespace System.Net.Mail; have you referenced that?

Comment: A `500` error means something went wrong server-side.  When you debug, where/when that that happen?  What is the actual server-side error?

Comment: The thing dosen't have a debug actualy, did i mistag something ? asp.net perhaps

Comment: Also, MsgBox is valid in windows forms but not in ASP.NET.

Comment: Ok guess i'll remove that, now the `include` is not blue like i often see... so it is not placed corretly ? This whole code is between <% %>

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: `"The thing dosen't have a debug actualy"` - How are you building this that there's no debugger?  You may want to start using an IDE like Visual Studio if you're going to be building ASP.NET web apps.

Comment: Yeah i know MVC, but this is some old script like code, and i haven't been able to run it in visual studio

Comment: There's no such thing as "Classic ASP.NET" Perhaps you're thinking of Web Forms.

Comment: This is hopeless, i'm going to make a call to a more recent online project, and handle the mail sending with the code behind of a modern web page. I can't delete this question since there are answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here (from property is not string):

```
 mail.From = "si@csnavigateurs.qc.ca"
```

I used this and worked:

```
 mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailAddress, name);// Email-ID of Sender
```

If you do not like use name of sender you can do this:

```
mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Try
  Dim SmtpServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

  SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true
  SmtpServer.Port = 25
  SmtpServer.Host = "csnavigateurs-qc-ca.mail.protection.outlook.com"

  Dim mail As New MailMessage()
  mail.From = "si@csnavigateurs.qc.ca"
  mail.To.Add("pelletiera77@csnavigateurs.qc.ca")
  mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
  mail.Body = "Testing the 1 and 2"
  SmtpServer.Send(mail)
  Response.Write("Success")
Catch ex As Exception
  Response.Write(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This should give you a clearer error message if it fails.

Comment: It will probably require an include somewhere